# Focus Freezing on tv-App and gives 'updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame' error. Stuck for a while

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, smart-tv

I am developing a TV App in Flutter and i already have a 3rd Party VideoPlayer ready but i am facing 'Focusing' issue when navigating back to the homePage from videoplayer. Page loses focus and Freezes. The only log error is as following:--> "E/FrameEvents( 5185): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame" Can someone plz help

I am using InkWell->Container->Image..
I am using 'onFocusChanged' property of InkWell to detect focus on image and 'onTap' to perform click and go to videoplayer. When navigating back from videoplayer to homePage i face this issue.The homePage loads but freezes and no action from remote is detected.